# rails geocoder can't customize model column names lat and lng

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

to my city.rb added

```
geocoded_by :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng
```

then when I call

```
city = City.near(city_name).first
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cities.latitude does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

in the city.rb the parameters passed to the geocoded_by method is in correct:

you need to specify first if you are doing normal geocoding means translate string address to latitude and longitude this the correct code should be like this

```
geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lon # ActiveRecord
```

Where address is the field where you store the string that will be searched for or it could be a method that creates a string to be used to get its equivalent latitude and longitude.

if you want to do the opposite, means get an address for specific coordinates then you should use:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude, :address => :location  # ActiveRecord
```

Comment: Neither of these work. The main issue is that my DB columns are :lat and :lng. I'm not trying to geocode anything from address to lat,lng I have the name and lat lng Im just trying to find other cities in my DB that are near by.